# Javascript Multiple Input calculator, Input are genrated by user then these input should do calculation

Tags: javascript, html

```js
    function addinput() {
        var input = parseInt(document.getElementById('num').value);
        var times = input
        
        
        for(var i=0 ; i<times; i++) {
         var newinput = parseInt(document.getElementById("textfileds").innerHTML+= "<input id=value> <br>");
        }
    }
    
    function calc(fn) {
        if (fn=="add") {
            var sum = document.getElementById("value").value += document.getElementById("value").value;
        }
    
        alert(sum);
    }
```

```html
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
            <div class="container">
                <h1 class="display-4 text-center">JS SIMPLE INPUT CALCULATOR</h1>
                <!-- <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p> -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
                <div class="input-group-prepend">
                    <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">How many inputs you want?</span>
                </div>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" id="num">
            </div>
            <button onsubmit onclick="addinput()">Submit</button>
            <p class="lead" id="textfileds"></p>
    
            <p class="lead" id="resulthere"></p>
            
            
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calc('add')">Add</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="calc('subtract')">Subtract</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="calc('multiply')">Multiply</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="calc('divide')">Divide</button>
        </div>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are having? Please explain what is not working for you and what you are trying to get it to do/

Comment: What is your porblem

Comment: I want to build a calculator that takes how many numbers you want to calculate if I enter 3  3 inputs appear then In these inputs i enter 1 , 2 & 3 then hit add so it will be 6

Comment: can anybody answer this question

Comment: It also keep on generating input, without removing older

Comment: Can I use jQuery? Should I show result in alert box ?

Comment: Yes You can also suggest me where I should improve my Javascript skill udemy course or any link please

Comment: Saad, don't you think we should have only 2 buttons. Imagine what happen when user give 4 inputs and click subtract? Should we set last 3 inputs negative and left first one. This is wrong I think. We should let user to add negative values and sum them up and show result. One button for both add and subtract and One button for both multiply and divide.

Comment: I think you must look at [JavaScript 2.0, The Complete Reference](http://digirivista.stvincentngp.edu.in/magazine/ebook/mcgraw-hill-javascript-the-complete-reference.pdf). It gives you in-depth knowledge of JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, @gpl for your Help I Really appreciate your time for reviewing the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- JQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function addinput() {
            var times = parseInt($('#num').val());
            if(times < 2)
                alert('Atleast 2 feilds are inputs for calculation.');
            else{
                $('#textfileds').html('');
                for(let i=0; i<times; i++)
                    $('#textfileds').append('<input type="number" class="value"> <br>');
            }
        }
        

        function calc(fn) {
            let feilds = $(".value");
            if(!feilds.length > 0)
                alert("You haven't provided data");
            else{
                let result = 0;
                switch(fn){
                    case 'add':
                    for(let i=0;i<feilds.length; i++)
                        result += parseInt(feilds[i].value);
                    break;
                    case 'subtract':
                    result = parseInt(feilds[0].value);
                    for(let i=1;i<feilds.length; i++)
                        result -= parseInt(feilds[i].value);
                    break;
                    case 'multiply':
                    result = 1;
                    for(let i=0;i<feilds.length; i++)
                        result *= parseInt(feilds[i].value);
                    break;
                    case 'divide':
                    result = parseInt(feilds[0].value);
                    for(let i=1;i<feilds.length; i++)
                        result /= parseInt(feilds[i].value);
                    break;
                }
                alert(result);
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="display-4 text-center">JS SIMPLE INPUT CALCULATOR</h1>
            <!-- <p class="lead">This is a modified jumbotron that occupies the entire horizontal space of its parent.</p> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">How many inputs you want?</span>
            </div>
            <input type="number" min="2" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" id="num">
        </div>
        <button onsubmit onclick="addinput()">Submit</button>
        <p class="lead" id="textfileds"></p>

        <p class="lead" id="resulthere"></p>


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="calc('add')">Add</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="calc('subtract')">Subtract</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="calc('multiply')">Multiply</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="calc('divide')">Divide</button>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```